# Sieve rule for catch-all email setup: Filter into folders based on alias

Tags: email, alias, email-filter, rules, sieve-rules

I'm running a catch-all email setup with my own domain (mydomain.tld). My hoster offers me to create arbitrary Sieve mail filter rules. I would like to create a rule that moves all incoming mail to a folder that equals the alias of the recipient (under my domain), even if the alias is unknown before.

In practice: If I receive an email via `<alias>@mydomain.tld`, I want a Sieve rule that automatically creates a folder named `alias` (if non existing) and moves the email into that folder.

A) Is this possible with Sieve?

B) Could you provide the necessary Sieve rule?

Answer (score 0):

It is that easy using the Sieve variables extension, which matches the regex `*` to a useable variable:

```
require ["fileinto", "variables", "mailbox"];
if header :matches "Delivered-To" "*@mydomain.tld" {
    fileinto :create "${1}";
}
```

EDIT: it is better to use "Delivered-To" (the envelope) than "To"